# How to use .mat file in C++ Visual Studio

Tags: c++, matlab, hyperlink

I am doing one of  my project on Pattern Recognition, Earlier I was training data with .mat file in Matlab, but now I need to use the same in C++.

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB makes available a [MAT-file API](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/read-and-write-matlab-mat-files-in-c-c-and-fortran.html) that can be used to read and write MAT files from C/C++ (or Fortran).

Answer (score 1):

Although there are some external libraries that allow c++ to read .mat files, most of them are not well supported, and can load files of much earlier versions. 
However, I would suggest you just save your variables in plain text format

```
save('output.txt', 'variable_name', '-ascii');
```

This is simple, since you work with numbers, and safe (any other language you use will be forever able to read text files, in constrast to relying on libraries that may not work next year). A file containing numbers has a natural interpretation, and can be viewed and manipulated by any program (excel, text editor, etc...)

If you are doing pattern recognition, you should probably keep your dataset in one file, with one pattern   per line, eg:

a1 a2 a3 a4 ... 1 0 0

where a_i is the value of the i-th attribute, and 1 0 0 is the class of the pattern. The weights of the neural network/ svm parameters/whatever else you are using, should be saved to a different, also text file. It will give you much less problems than a .mat file, the contents of which you cannot view and use in any other way other than loading it on matlab.

Comment: It's not at all true that you cannot view or use .mat files in any other way than loading it into MATLAB. MATLAB itself makes available an API specifically designed to read .mat files directly into C/C++ and Fortran (which is completely supported).